# Error in cross product

Tags: vector

I want to take the cross product of two rather complicated vectors but Mathematica gives me error:

Here is the input:
[image: code]

The error I get is "The expression pu cannot be used as a part specification."

Do I have a syntax problem or is it because I need to name different variables? (I am new to this software)

Thank you.

edit: I changed the code and got this result after simplifying:

{(r Sqrt[R^2 q^4+r^2 Cos[[p x]]^2 q^4+2 r R Cos[[p x]] q^4+p^2 r^2] Sin[[p x]] (q (R+r cos(p x)) Sin[[q x]]+p r cos(q x) sin(p x)) p^2+(R^2 q^4+r^2 Cos[[p x]]^2 q^4+2 r R Cos[[p x]] q^4+p^2 r^2) rpCos(p x) ((p^2+q^2) r cos(q x) Cos[[p x]]+q (q R cos(q x)-2 p r Sin[[q x]] sin(p x))))/(((R+r Cos[[p x]])^2 q^4+p^2 r^2)^(3/2) ((r^2 (q^2 r (R+r cos(p x)) sin(2 p x)-2 (-p^2 r^2-q^2 (R+r cos(p x))^2) Sin[[p x]])^2 p^4)/(4 (p^2 r^2+q^2(R+r Cos[[p x]])^2)^3)+((-p^2 r^2-q^2 (R+r cos(p x))^2) (-2 p r Cos[[q x]] sin(p x) q-q^2 R Sin[[q x]]-Cos[[p x]] Sin[[qx]] r(p^2+q^2))-p r q^2(R+rCos(p x)) sin(p x) (q (R+r cos(p x)) cos(q x)-p r Sin[[q x]] sin(p x)))^2/(p^2 r^2+q^2(R+r cos(p x))^2)^3+(p r q^2(R+r Cos[[p x]]) sin(p x) (q (R+r cos(p x)) Sin[[q x]]+p r Cos[[q x]] sin(p x))-(q^2(R+r cos(p u))^2-p^2 r^2) ((p^2+q^2) r cos(p x) Cos[[q x]]+q (q R cos(q x)-2 p r Sin[[q x]] sin(p x))))^2/(p^2 r^2+q^2(R+r Cos[[p x]])^2)^3)^0.5),((R^2 q^4+r^2 Cos[[p x]]^2 q^4+2 r R Cos[[p x]] q^4+p^2 r^2) rpCos(p x) ((R q^2+(p^2+q^2) r Cos[[p x]]) Sin[[q x]]+2 p q r Cos[[q x]] sin(p x))-p^2 r Sqrt[R^2 q^4+r^2 Cos[[p x]]^2 q^4+2 r R Cos[[p x]] q^4+p^2 r^2] Sin[[p x]] (q (R+r cos(p x)) cos(q x)-p r Sin[[q x]] sin(p x)))/(((R+r Cos[[p x]])^2 q^4+p^2 r^2)^(3/2) ((r^2 (q^2 r (R+r cos(p x)) sin(2 p x)-2 (-p^2 r^2-q^2 (R+r cos(p x))^2) Sin[[p x]])^2 p^4)/(4 (p^2 r^2+q^2(R+r Cos[[p x]])^2)^3)+((-p^2 r^2-q^2 (R+r cos(p x))^2) (-2 p r Cos[[q x]] sin(p x) q-q^2 R Sin[[q x]]-Cos[[p x]] Sin[[qx]] r(p^2+q^2))-p r q^2(R+rCos(p x)) sin(p x) (q (R+r cos(p x)) cos(q x)-p r Sin[[q x]] sin(p x)))^2/(p^2 r^2+q^2(R+r cos(p x))^2)^3+(p r q^2(R+r Cos[[p x]]) sin(p x) (q (R+r cos(p x)) Sin[[q x]]+p r Cos[[q x]] sin(p x))-(q^2(R+r cos(p u))^2-p^2 r^2) ((p^2+q^2) r cos(p x) Cos[[q x]]+q (q R cos(q x)-2 p r Sin[[q x]] sin(p x))))^2/(p^2 r^2+q^2(R+r Cos[[p x]])^2)^3)^0.5),(q ((R^2 q^2+r R cos(p x) q^2+2 p^2 r^2 sin^2(p x)) Sin[[q x]]^2-2 p q r (R+r cos(p x)) (cos(q x)-Cos[[q x]]) sin(p x) Sin[[q x]]+1/2 (p^2+q^2) r (R+r cos(p x)) Cos[[p x]] (2 Sin[[q x]]^2+cos(2 q x)+1)+cos(q x) (R (R+r cos(p x)) cos(q x) q^2+2 p^2 r^2 Cos[[q x]] sin^2(p x))))/((R^2 q^4+r^2 Cos[[p x]]^2 q^4+2 r R Cos[[p x]] q^4+p^2 r^2) ((r^2 (q^2 r (R+r cos(p x)) sin(2 p x)-2 (-p^2 r^2-q^2 (R+r cos(p x))^2) Sin[[p x]])^2 p^4)/(4 (p^2 r^2+q^2(R+r Cos[[p x]])^2)^3)+((-p^2 r^2-q^2 (R+r cos(p x))^2) (-2 p r Cos[[q x]] sin(p x) q-q^2 R Sin[[q x]]-Cos[[p x]] Sin[[qx]] r(p^2+q^2))-p r q^2(R+rCos(p x)) sin(p x) (q (R+r cos(p x)) cos(q x)-p r Sin[[q x]] sin(p x)))^2/(p^2 r^2+q^2(R+r cos(p x))^2)^3+(p r q^2(R+r Cos[[p x]]) sin(p x) (q (R+r cos(p x)) Sin[[q x]]+p r Cos[[q x]] sin(p x))-(q^2(R+r cos(p u))^2-p^2 r^2) ((p^2+q^2) r cos(p x) Cos[[q x]]+q (q R cos(q x)-2 p r Sin[[q x]] sin(p x))))^2/(p^2 r^2+q^2(R+r Cos[[p x]])^2)^3)^0.5)}

Answer (score 1):

All the functions in Mathematica begins with a capital letter, you should modify `cos` to `Cos`, `sin` to `Sin`; and the function for cross product is `Cross`.When you multiply two variables, either put a `*` or a space between them, or they will be considered as another variable.

`[]` are only used for functions,e.g.`Sin[x]`, please change your `[]`s to `()`s when indicating arithmetic priority. And if you want to get a proper result for the cross product when you have components, you should use `Cross[{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}]` instead of `Cross[3 OverHat[i] + 4 OverHat[j] + 5 OverHat[k], 
 3 OverHat[i] + 4 OverHat[j] + 5 OverHat[k]]`

----Update:---
There are still many syntax errors in your modified code, inferring from your result. First, things like `Cos[[x]]` should be `Cos[x]`; second, I still see something like `cos(x)` ; and `Sin^2[x]` should be Sin[x]^2. I suggest you to use Find and Replace to make it easier.

Please copy the original code instead of the result.

Comment: Thank you. I did everything you told and unfortunately got a meter long answer.

Comment: @user27670 try `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` then?